# Angular error in P-fileupload when ng build --prod

Tags: angular, primeng

In my Angular project, when I try to run `ng build --prod`, I have this issue in the `p-fileUpload` from [primeng](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/fileupload):

> `media.component.html` (5,81): Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target

But if I use the `ng build` without `--prod`, it builds normally. Same if I use `ng serve`.

This is the code:

```
<p-fileUpload mode="basic" #fileInput name="files" url="{{url}}" auto="auto" (onBeforeUpload)="onBeforeUpload($event)" chooseLabel="Allega file"
         (onUpload)="onUpload($event)" (onProgress)="onProgress($event)" (onError)="onError($event)" multiple="multiple" (onBeforeSend)="onBeforeSend($event)"
         accept="{{uploadAcceptedFormat}}" maxFileSize="{{maxUploadSize}}"></p-fileUpload>
```

And this is the method:

```
  onError(event: any) {
    this.showProgressBar = false;
    console.log(event);
    this.openSnackBar('Upload fallito')
  }

onBeforeSend(event) {

    event.xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token'));

    this.showProgressBar = true;
  }

  onUpload(event) {
    this.openSnackBar('Upload completato')
    this.progressValue = 0;
    this.showProgressBar = false;
    this.reloadMedias();
  }

  onBeforeUpload(event) {}

  onProgress(event) {
    if (event.originalEvent.loaded !== 0) {
      this.progressValue = (event.originalEvent.loaded / event.originalEvent.total) * 100;
    }
  }
```

Like all other methods in the fileupload I have 1 event, so why this give me errors only with `--prod`

Comment: Could you post your whole error please ?

Comment: Are you sure the error does not come from another event listener like `(onUpload)`, `(onBeforeUpload)`, etc..?

Comment: @n00dl3 Probably yes, but all the methods have 1 event like onError, I update

Comment: Which versions of angular and primeng are you using?

Comment: angular 4.4.4 and primeng 4.3.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason if I delete the `onBeforeUpload(event) {}` method it works and build normally

Answer (score -2):

Try to build with this command :

```
ng build --prod --aot=false;
```

Comment: You should not do that. It just hides the problem, not solves it. `--aot` flag compiles your code beforehand and detects the problems in your code.

Comment: Yes now it builds... but why?

Comment: @Alessandro don't do that. You have something wrong in your code and `JIT` compiler does not detect that. You will probably run into that bug on runtime.

Comment: I answered this question according to build problem @BunyaminCoskuner why did you rate me negative ??

Comment: Because, your suggestion is not a real solution but a workaround. Anyone who sees this post may try it out and see the problem "goes away" but in reality, it just hides it.

Comment: But it works in many cases how can you know it will not work on run time

Comment: `AOT` compiles your code on your server, `JIT` does the same thing on browser. If you don't come across that bug within your tests, you may not be aware of it. Some user may, though. I assume you wouldn't want that.

Comment: @EslamAshour it does not allow me to remove my rate unless you edit it. So, explain the problem I mentioned above in your post and I'll remove my rate.